# Time Signature Trouble

Tags: piano, chords, time-signatures

I am a church pianist who writes original hymns, recently I have taken on the task of writing sheet music for my songs. I am having trouble with this one. I cannot figure out the time signature on this song. ---- Also feel free to comment on my chords.

[Audio File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0f91vpyx50x0di3/2144696554_ChangeMeLord%281%29.mp3.6e89ffd19241cebfabfdf8a49c2974fc.mp3?dl=0)

(Eb)Change me(Ab- A°-Bb7) Lord

Make me new (Eb-Gm-Cm7) again

Change me (Fm7-Bb/F) Lord and

(Bb7)make me pure(Eb-Eb11)within

Sanctify my (Ab- A°-Bb7) life and

cleanse my (Eb-Gm-Cm7)mind

Change me (Fm7-Bb/F)Lord and

(Bb11)make me just like (Eb)you

Comment: I cannot be completely sure, since, I have to admit, your timing is not very precise. But that seems like a 9/8 with phrases starting in the upbeat: "Change me" is on the third beat (the last 3/8), "Lord" is on the first two (the first 6/8) and so on.

Comment: When you’re writing, why not just decide what you want the time signature to be? Start tapping on something while you sing and use that to create a rhythmic foundation to help you decide which time signature to choose

Comment: It's almost impossible from the information given - the vocal doesn't stay in a particularly static timing. The chords shown don't help, as we don't know where they come in each line. Better to play with block chords, which will most likely give you an answer anyway.